# Answers blinking when clicked?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I noticed today that answers are sometimes blinking when clicked on. Very weird. Doesn’t seem to happen with questions, nor does it consistently happen with answers. When it happens, it happens consistently for all answers on that page, but reloading or going elsewhere and coming back may leave the page with no blinking.

Comment: [It's fixed now.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283925/posts-disappear-briefly-then-reload-when-i-click-them#comment921517_284194)

Answer (score 6):

This is a new bug, yes. [It's been reported on MSE already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283925/answers-disappear-briefly-then-reload-when-i-click-them), so we should go vote that up. This question is probably still helpful because it shows the extent of the problem among SEs.